# Returning a type depending on the parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I want to have such a function that it's return type will be decided within the function(depending on the **value** of the parameter), but failed implementing it. (template specialization maybe?)

```
// half-pseudo code
auto GetVar(int typeCode)
{
  if(typeCode == 0)return int(0);
  else if(typeCode == 1)return double(0);
  else return std::string("string");
}
```

And I want to use it without specifying the type as:

```
auto val = GetVar(42); // val's type is std::string
```

Comment: Functions can only have one return type. C++ is statically typed. Maybe you're looking for `boost::variant`.

Comment: @chris: How about template functions, auto functions?

Comment: This doesn't look like real code, but a contrived example. If you can show us what you are trying to achieve, maybe we can suggest something better

Comment: @Ausser Templates are instantiated once for each type where it's needed during compilation. The type of  `auto` is deduced during compilation, it's not determined at runtime.

Comment: maybe this is an attempt at a Factory pattern? Are the various types you might return related in some way?

Comment: @Ausser It's possible with template functions. Take a look at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) for a tutorial on how to use templates.

Comment: @Nasser it's not a real code, yes. It's the example usage aiming to clarify my need.

Comment: @JohnOdom, Not based on runtime values. Directly, anyway, since templates could certainly aid in a different approach.

Comment: @KateGregory Factory pattern returns a base class pointer AFAIK ?

Comment: Overload resolution (whether template or 'plain') does not consider return type.

Comment: is `typeCode` known at compile time, or is it determined at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not work, you would have to give the parameter at compile time. The following would work:

```
template<int Value>
double GetVar() {return 0.0;};

template<>
int GetVar<42>() {return 42;}

auto x = GetVar<0>(); //type(x) == double
auto y = GetVar<42>(); //type(x) == int
```

Another version would be to pass std::integral_constant, like this:

```
template<int Value>
using v = std::integral_constant<int, Value>;

template<typename T>
double GetVar(T) {return 0;};

int GetVar(v<42>) {return 42;};

auto x = GetVar(v<0>()); //type(x) == double
auto y = GetVar(v<42>()); //type(x) == int
```

Answer (score 1):

From C++17 it's also possible to use `if constexpr` to keep a similar structure as the code in the question:

```
template<int typeCode>
auto GetVar()
{
  if constexpr(typeCode == 0) return int(0);
  else if constexpr(typeCode == 1) return double(0);
  else return std::string("string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since c++ is object oriented we can have all of the options inherit from a parent class and then return an instance of that parent class.

Alternatively we could try the  void * return type.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand how this is related with my question.

Comment: two possible methods to return different structured data, keep in mind you can also overload the function to return different things depending on what arguments are passed in to it

Comment: @JoshuaByer if you think about overriding a virtual function, then you're stuck with covariant returning (can at most return a pointer to the derived class).

Comment: I wouldn't say "C++ is object oriented". Rather it's a multi paradigm language that happens to contain features to *support* object oriented programming, but it's perfectly possible to write C++ programs that don't use OOP in *any* way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// foo1 overloads are enabled via the return type
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type 
foo1(T t) 
{
    std::cout << "foo1: float\n";
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at std::enable_if doc. Possibly you may use it to create return param type that depends on the value and not just on type