# C++ Function return type as template

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, return-type

I want to write a function to return different class objects depending on the value of a parameter. Returning class objects are templated. I give the class name as a template argument to the function,

```
template< class T >
static T FindClassObjects(int var){
   if(var==1)
      return T<float>(var);
   else
      return T<int>(var);
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Let's try googling _c++ return diferent type depending on parameter_. Hmm... Possible duplicate of [Returning different data type depending on the data (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930932/returning-different-data-type-depending-on-the-data-c) or [Returning a type depending on the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088983/returning-a-type-depending-on-the-parameter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to write a function to return different class objects depending on the value of a parameter. [...] Can I do this?

Short answer: no.

Long answer.

The C/C++ languages are strongly typed; every single function return a type that must be known at compile type.

So it's impossible to have a function that return a type that depend from a value known at runtime.

It's different if you known the value `var` at compile time: in this case you can develop different functions that return different types and compile time select which function to call depending to the `var` value.

Anyway, you can go round this limit in different ways.

If you can use C++17, you can return a `std::any`, that can contain any type; or (better, I suppose) a `std::variant`, that can contain a value in a prefixed list of types.

Otherwise, if the different typed have a common base class, you (by example) can return a pointer to a base class.

Comment: Thank you. I think you gave me the solution. All these classes have a common base class. So I can use that. But the problem is the base class is not a template. So how can I know which type I should use to instantiate.

Comment: @user3566905 - welcome in the world of c++ polymorphism! Question/suggestion: the base class can contain a value that can say you which type is the derived class?